# tier price working on view and list page but not in cart page

Tags: addtocart, ce-1.9.2.2, tierprice

I have applied Tier price on my website. It shows "As low as" on list price and also applies successfully to view the product page. But when I add the product to the cart, it doesn't apply.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_cart_item->getCalculationPrice()) ;
```

This line display price in cart page. how can I apply tier price on this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tier price should be lower than special price.
2. Special price should be lower than Regular price (Price).
3. No need to modify any files to show tier price at the listing and detailed page as well as At the Cart page.
4. Try the following to show the Tier Price.

   ```
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
     //your_product_id $childProducts =
     Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                         ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);    
   foreach($childProducts as $child) {
         $id = $child->getId();
         $pro = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); //load                        
   associated product id
         if($pro['tier_price'] != NULL) {
              foreach($pro['tier_price'] as $tier){
                 echo $tier['price'].'<br/>';
             }
         } }
   ```

Comment: I apply this rule but in cart it shows only base price of product .